# ASP.NET Core MVC Subaction in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Administration Controller with a Users method. And I would like to add a “new” Subaction with a new View to this method. The URL should look like this: /administration/users/new

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you mean is "Area".

So, in Asp.Net Core 2 routing, there are areas, there are controllers, there are actions and optionally parameters.

You can have routing middleware configured something like.  You can specify area attribute on the contorllers.

Administrator would be area - Users would be controller and New would be action. 
This should keep the code clean as this is merely using the default routing middleware.

For better understanding of Areas, please refer: https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/08/25/asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-areas/

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=dashboard}/{action=index}/{id?}"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}"
);
```

Comment: I set up an Administration Area and copied all stuff over, after that I recognized that the Tag Helper in the Views not working. I searched a little and found only this solution: `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Is that the only solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: @TeraNovaLP - it seems it is the syntax that we have to use for tag helpers. I could not find any other way for this.  Please refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 3):

This is really just a question about routing. Just add a method in the Administration controller and tell MVC what the route is with a `Route` attribute. For example:

```
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
    }

    [Route("users/new")] //This is the important part here
    public ActionResult NewUser()
    {
    }
}
```

You could also configure the routing inside your `Startup.cs` class, but I find it easier to do with attribute routing. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several methods to do it 
[Routes at .net core](https://stormpath.com/blog/routing-in-asp-net-core)

try attributes

```
[Route("users/new")]
public IActionResult New()
{
    return View();
}
```